# Android dynamic list-view alignment

Tags: android, layout

I have one question for Android Layout I am trying to create a dynamic list view in alert dialog .!
As below

```
Column1                 Column2                   Column3                  Column4
hjdgfhdbfhjnb        hjdjhfjkhkjnhjkln                 dhjfjdkh                  hdjghjd
hgchg676          kjkcvkjv                 hjchjcc                 cjjkcjclkjnn
```

This is happening but i want in pure align way . I am using this but not working for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="4" >

  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orderTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black_gradient"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/search_batchnumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:textColor="@color/black_gradient"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/search_inventory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:textColor="@color/black_gradient"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/search_rate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black_gradient"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

     </LinearLayout>
```

So please give me suggestion, How can I do in align way?

Comment: Basically I am not able to align my list view properly. I have included this layout in a ListView.Some of the fields are have bigger lengths and some are smaller, I want there starting point always to be at same point in each row.

Comment: Column1 ,Column2...etc are in different layout???                ,

Comment: They are in same layout. orderTitle, search_batchnumber, search_inventory, search_rate are coulumns, all are textview an in same layout.

Comment: you have applied weight so you have to set your all textView width to 0.

Comment: @PG_Android making width 0 worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orderTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/black_gradient"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_batchnumber"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/black_gradient"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_inventory"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/black_gradient"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_rate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@color/black_gradient"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>

try this.
```

Comment: Also do note, first row of yours which displays column name, should follow same layout design as above, once you do that everything will be alighned as u want.

Answer (score 0):

change linearLayout width to android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: This is not solution for question

Comment: @AndoMasahashi without Linearlayout match_parent weight property will not work and apart from that their is nothing ... may be just setting gravity

Comment: @PG_Android and AndoMasahashi

Comment: @Crazy you can set 0dp and weightsum property